# Java Uri.fromFile path issue

Tags: android, path, uri

Ok I've finally got the problem down to this method.

I have a File object called file, when I do a toString() it outputs the following

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ecohelp/IMG_ecohelp_20131016_214242.jpg
```

Now after the the File object is inserted into the following method

```
Uri uriFile = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

When I do a uriFile.toString() it outputs the following

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ecohelp/IMG_ecohelp_20131016_214242.jpg
```

Now I tried removing the / at the start of "/storage..." but it still doesn't work, anyone know why this happens? It should be file:// as like anything else but it puts on three of them.

I was trying to mimic this for images: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media

I get this error when trying to save a file:

```
10-16 22:16:39.945: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:2, request=100, 
result=-1, data=null} to activity 
{com.example.ecohelp/com.example.ecohelp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

This is considered correct behavior, as the URI consists of the following elements:

- Scheme: `file://`
- Path: `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ecohelp/IMG_ecohelp_20131016_214242.jpg`

All file URI's usually have 3 slashes, two for the scheme, one saying that the path should start at root on the filesystem (`/`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's because of the extra / character after file://.  In fact, the API mentions an example, and it includes files:///.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile(java.io.File)

Based on the error message, seems like you're not passing data to your MainActivity properly.  Perhaps we can see more code?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the string you receive is the correct URI.

In short, a URI syntax's goes as:

(scheme)://(path)

where path might contains many more subfields (have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax for a more complete discussion on these subfields).

Now, for the "file" scheme, the path is wither a relative local path or an absolute local path. Absolute path, on Unix-based systems, WILL begin with a slash.

So your string is perfectly correct:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ecohelp/IMG_ecohelp_20131016_214242.jpg

means that the scheme is "file", and the path is the absolute local file: "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ecohelp/IMG_ecohelp_20131016_214242.jpg", which is the correct location for the File object that you ceated.

As for your NullPointerException, I don't think it is related to the URI nor the file. I don't know much in Android development, but I believe you should have an onActivityResult method somewhere around. Could it be that you invoke a method on some variable there, without first checking for null values?